# Updates for Ubuntu LTS Desktop versus LTS Server

Tags: release-management

I still have Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Desktop on my systems.  10.04 Desktop has reached end of life.

I understand that means there will be no more security updates for this product.  Is that correct?

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Server is still supported for another year.  Will the security updates for the Server work for the Desktop?

If I do an update from the 10.04 LTS Desktop, what gets updated?  Any kernel updates?

Comment: Why don't you simply update to the next LTS version e.g. 12.04 or even 14.04 using `sudo do-release-upgrade` in the command line? See the supported version list here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS

Comment: Actually what ceased to have support are the packages. If you install the "server" you won't have desktop applications (like firefox) updated.

Answer (score 2):

None. Absolutely nothing. The packages that gets installed in the server version are shared with the desktop version, they are the same packages just that distributed with different propose. What ceased to have support are the packages that aren't normally found in a server, that means that all GUI's package, and anything not in the main repository, hasn't been updated.